# Keep From Pushing 2 View Controllers at Once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, frame, touches

In my app setup, I have a navigation controller with 4 ImageViews.  1 of them can be dragged around, while the other 3 are stationary at the top section of the view.  Using the code below, I have it set up so that the user drags the one image view to the image view of where he wants to go.  So to get to view 1, he drags the movable image view to image view 1, and so on.  The issue is that with the width of the image views, it is possible for the selector view to touch two at one time, which creates a nesting view controller issue.  Is there a way I can keep this from happening, short of moving the image views so far away that it is impossible for more than one to be selected at a time?

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // If the touch was in the placardView, move the placardView to its location
    if ([touch view] == clock) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.tabBarController.view];
        clock.center = location;
        BOOL isIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect(clock.frame, prayer.frame);
        BOOL isIntersecting2 = CGRectIntersectsRect(clock.frame, fasting.frame);
        BOOL isIntersecting3 = CGRectIntersectsRect(clock.frame, study.frame);

        if(isIntersecting){
            [self schedulePrayer];
            NSLog(@"prayer");
        }
        if(isIntersecting2){
            [self scheduleFasting];
            NSLog(@"fasting");
        }
        if(isIntersecting3){
            [self scheduleStudying];
            NSLog(@"Studying");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use **if ... else if ... else if**? Then only one will be triggered at a time.

Comment: If you will post this as an answer, @Ricky I will accept it.

Comment: Posted as requested. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use **if ... else if ... else if**?

```
 if(isIntersecting){
            [self schedulePrayer];
            NSLog(@"prayer");
        }
 else if(isIntersecting2){
            [self scheduleFasting];
            NSLog(@"fasting");
        }
 else if(isIntersecting3){
            [self scheduleStudying];
            NSLog(@"Studying");
        }
```

Then, only one will be triggered at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Create another BOOL "isTouching" and make it global. Then inside your if(isIntersecting) set "isTouching" to global, and add "isTouching" as a condition such that:

```
if ([touch view] == clock && (!isTouching))
```

You also need to set isTouching to false in the case that the UIImageView is not on any of the intersecting views and you should be good to go :)

That should be enough hints for you to solve your problem, but if you'd like more clarification let me know.

Comment: That's a shame. Because I just tried out the exact scenario in XCode and my solution is fine. But since you already downvoted i'm not really inclined to explain further. Sorry

Comment: If you're going to take the time to answer a question, maybe answer the question and not say things like, "That should be enough hints".  I didn't post a question hoping to get hints.

Comment: Like I said, your answer should never contain the phrase, "That should be enough hints".  That makes the reader assume that you are perfect, know everything, and are being very condescending.